# what is this window.top performs in my script ? is this frames checking?

Tags: javascript, windows

Hello I have this script below in which I am a bit confused about the task that perform this script ...This script I sniped from a project I am working on.So if You guys can help to understand it a bit or put me on the road ..below is the script

```
if (window.top !== window.self) window.top.location = window.self.location.href;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common code, checking to see if the page is loaded inside an iframe, if it is, it will pop out of the iframe.

---

[`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) represents the "topmost window", the one whos URL you see in your address bar.

[`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)represent the window that is running the currentl script.

The script says, if the topmost window is not the one running this script then change the URL of the top script to the URL of the script that is running this code.

Comment: so  it means this script will not allow the page to be opened outside top window or inside any frames?is it ?

Comment: @ALPHORMATE - yes, that's right. it prevents the page from being opened in a frame.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once  . In your answer you said the top window URL will be changed to the URL in which the script is running (in this case frame) So how this prevent page from being opened in a frame?

Comment: because if it is loaded in a frame it will take over the top window. try it.

Comment: @ALPHORMATE - here's an example... https://plnkr.co/edit/CcmxZn36ca7wvc1120Rt?p=catalogue

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once ...THANKS it works now after testing it

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your script running in an iFrame.

`window.top` refers to the parent window in this scenario.

`window.top !== window.self` tests if your script is running inside an iFrame

And if so, `window.top.location = window.self.location.href;` makes sure that the parent window will take the same url as the one running in the iFrame.

This is some sort of a security check to make sure that your scripts would always run in topmost windows.

Comment: thanks for post because I wanted to ask about the purpose of this checking which you have been answering with your last post ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

(window.top !== window.self) These kind of checks we use generally, if we are executing inside an iframe.
window.self means the window from which we are executing(current frame), window.top refers to the outer most frame.